# How to group array as a key to an object

Tags: javascript

**I'm struggling to group array as a key to an object.**

```js
var a = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"]
var b = ["apple", "banana", "Orange"];
var obj = {};
a.forEach((x) => {
    b.forEach((y) => {

        obj[x] = y;
    })

})
console.log(obj)
```

OUTPUT:

```js
{​fruit1:apple,fruit2:banana:fruit3:orange}​
```

Comment: Could any one help me..

Answer (score 2):

In the inner loop you rewrite all object values with the last element of `b`. Try this to utilize the index argument of `.forEach()`:

```js
var a = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"];
var b = ["apple", "banana", "Orange"];
var obj = {};

a.forEach((x, i) => {
  obj[x] = b[i];
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zipObj](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) function from [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) library which convert your arrays to an object just like below:

```js
const a = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"]
const b = ["apple", "banana", "Orange"];
const obj = R.zipObj(a, b) //{"fruit1": "apple", "fruit2": "banana", "fruit3": "Orange"}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of entries and then an object from it.

```js
const
    keys = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"],
    values = ["apple", "banana", "Orange"],
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]));

console.log(result);
```